# How do I convert this C line to C++? using cout command

Tags: c++, c

```
printf("%-8s - %s\n", c->name ? c->name : "", c->help);
```

Answer (score 12):

I think what you're looking for is

```
cout << left << setw(8) << (c->name ? c->name : "") << " - " << c->help << endl;
```

The `left` and `setw(8)` manipulators together have the same effect as the `%-8s` formatting specifier in `printf`.  You will need to `#include <iomanip>` in order for this to work, though, because of the use of `setw`.

**EDIT**: As Matthieu M. pointed out, the above will permanently change `cout` so that any padding operations print out left-aligned.  Note that this isn't as bad as it might seem; it only applies when you explicitly use `setw` to set up some padding.  You have a few options for how to deal with this.  First, you could just enforce the discipline that before using `setw`, you always use either the `left` or `right` manipulators to left- or right-align the text, respectively.  Alternatively, you can use the `flags` and `setf` function to capture the current state of the flags in `cout`:

```
ios_base::fmtflags currFlags = cout.flags();
cout << left << setw(8) << (c->name ? c->name : "") << " - " << c->help << endl;
cout.setf(currFlags, ios_base::adjustfield);
```

This works in three steps.  The first line reads the current formatting flags from `cout`, including how it's currently aligning padded output.  The second line actually prints out the value.  Finally, the last line resets `cout`'s output flags for internal alignment to their old value.

Personally, I think the first option is more attractive, but it's definitely good to know that the second one exists since it's technically more correct.

Comment: Uglyness! My eyes! THEY BURN! +1

Comment: @Marlon- I've never found a single good I/O library with formatting that doesn't cause eyes to burn.  I personally like this version more than the `printf` because it's a bit clearer with what it's doing, even if it is a lot more verbose.  Also, I once broke my comma/left-angle-brace key, and so for the longest time I dreaded ever having to type something like this out. :-)

Comment: @Marlon A few line breaks would help relieve some of the pain. I also recommend you take Aspirin ++.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I don't think this is clearer because it doesn't put the format specifier in one place for quick overview. This can be a pain to maintain when you only want an extra space somewhere in the middle. Still, +1.

Comment: Note that the "<< endl" at the end of the line will also flush the stream, which is not the same as a simple "\n". For a complete equivalent for what you wrote, use "<< "\n"" instead of "<< endl". Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n

Comment: @templatetypedef: unfortunately it's not equivalent. Manipulators are pretty long lived, and therefore all subsequent inputs will be affected by `left`. You thus need to restore the previous manipulator. That's the most important issue with IO Streams, manipulators introduce global state (eurk).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: You are correct that `left` will stick around afterwards.  However, I don't believe that entirely invalidates this answer.  First, if you enforce the discipline of always specifying what sort of alignment you want before using `setw`, this is irrelevant.  Second, `left` only has an effect when `setw` is used, so it will not adversely affect the output for other operations, especially if the aforementioned discipline is used.  Also, is there something specifically I can do to get you to remove the downvote?  I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my answer.

Comment: @templatetypedef: show how to capture/restore the previous setting, it's something that really catches beginners unaware.

Comment: @Matthieu: I noticed, removed my comment. Second error I catch on fredosaurus in a week...

Comment: @larsmans: personally, I'm hardpressed to ever remember... I've got a simple .cpp file I keep on the side to test this kind of things quickly :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I just never use the manipulators except with short-lived streams. Otherwise, it's `boost::format` all the way.

Comment: @Matthieu M.- Can you check over what I have and confirm that it's correct?  I think this works out correctly.

Comment: @larsmans: the only issue with Boost.Format is that the compiler does not warn if by mistake you didn't provided enough parameters (or you provided too much) or if the type mismatched... `printf` (and co) is usually checked by compilers (though only usable for PODs).

Comment: @templatetypedef: looks good (ahem... *correct*), I've removed my downvote :) I don't really feel like upvoting though, because of the messy syntax this impose (nothing against you, more of a peeve against the IOStream library).

Comment: @Matthieu M.- Thanks for looking over that so quickly and for catching that slip-up.  And no offense taken for not upvoting; it definitely is messy!

Comment: The use of `ios_base::fmtflags` is not exception-safe in general. It's better to use the Boost ios state saver for this purpose (but then, why not use `format`?).

Comment: @larsmans- True, though the question was mostly on how to use `cout` and so I assumed that the OP's question relates mostly to standard C++ (aka without Boost).  Making this Boostier certainly wouldn't hurt, but I think it's beyond the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: @Jörgen Sigvardsson: "Not trying to start a pseudo religious debate, but [starts a pseudo-religious debate]". In other words, "I know it's wrong, but what the heck, I'll do it anyway"? Please don't do that.

Answer (score 9):

If you've got the Boost libraries:

```
std::cout << boost::format("%-8s - %s\n") % (c->name ? c->name : "") % c->help;
```

Comment: +1 for `format`, clearly the closer to the original, so it'll be much easier.